# Mongoose creating empty arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the code below:

```
var questionSchema = new schema({
  title: String,
  subtitle: String,
  required: Boolean,
  type: String,
  create_date: Date,
  question_id: Number,
  suvey_id: Number,
  items: Array
});
var question = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
var quest = getMyQuestion();

var record = new question({
  title: quest.question,
  subtitle: quest.subtitle,
  required: quest.answer_required,
  type: quest.question_type,
  create_date: quest.create_date,
  question_id: quest.id,
  survey_id: quest.survey_id
});

record.save();
```

But when I pull this record from my database it always has the `items` attribute defined as an empty array (rather than not being there at all).

Is mongoose doing this on purpose?  If so why?  Would it be a bad idea for me to try and force the attribute to not be defined at all (rather than being defined as an empty array)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mongoose does do this on purpose, though I'm not sure why. If you set the properties that you don't want stored as `undefined`, they will be excluded from the document.

[set field as empty for mongo object using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636938/set-field-as-empty-for-mongo-object-using-mongoose)

Answer (score 18):

You can set the default to `undefined`. From the Mongoose docs:

```
var ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
  toys: {
    type: [ToySchema],
    default: undefined
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662330/6053299) it is done by default in order to enable Model to perform standard operations on arrays which is possible when the array is empty but not when it is `null` or `undefined`.

However it is possible to completely remove a property with an empty array. According to the latest updates on [this thread](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1335) the following modification to the schema would work:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
   items: { type: Array, default: void 0 } // <-- override the array default to be undefined
});
```