# Empty Array left in Mongoose blank object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple Mongoose object:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Flight', new Schema({ 
    name: String,
    nkr: Number,
    outbound: {
        nkr: Number,
        weight: Number,
        facilities: Array,
    }
});
```

And when I create a new blank flight, I get back data as follows:

```
"fligts": [{
    "_id": "55e8642d4666a2141019a372",
    "extra" :  {
        "facilities": []
     }
}]
```

This is inconvenient as if i run `flight.outbound.length` returns `1`. I want a black `outbound` object if nothing is entered, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose creates empty array by default. So you need to explicitly set `facilities` field to `undefined` before saving

check this
[Mongoose creating empty arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713650/mongoose-creating-empty-arrays)