# Object's array property from Mongo is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm successfully getting a document from my Mongo DB, but everything in that document is showing undefined. Here's an example:

```
...
  const user = await UserModel.findById(user_id).exec(); //Getting user normally

  console.log(user); // Shows the object normally with the "push_subscriptions" property
  console.log(user.push_subscriptions); // Shows undefined
  console.log(user.email); //Shows the email normally
...
```

Here's the screenshot of console:

[image]

Here is the "push_subscriptions" part of User's schema:

```
...
  push_subscriptions: {
    type: Array,
  },
...
```

Comment: Could `push_subscriptions` be something that [gets added later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660832/element-children-has-elements-but-returns-empty-htmlcollection), after the `console.log(user)`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, it is in my DB

Comment: Very puzzling....

Comment: very unusual, can you show us the Shema maybe?

Comment: @JohnRC yeah, I agree :D . Maybe it's somehow related to asynchronous operations or something?

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty sure, in a minute :)

Comment: put default:[ ] in your schema

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713650/mongoose-creating-empty-arrays mongoose does for you even database doesn't contain any array.

Comment: Might there be hex characters in the key `push_subscriptions` that do not show up on the console log of the object, so the string `push_subscriptions` does not match it. Try extracting all the keys of the user object then log the key itself and its value using forEach.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070111/13236005

Comment: console.log uses Object.inspect() doesn't it? Has Mongoose modified the .inspect() function so that properties that aren't on the object but are in the schema are added to the output, but the property is not accessible directly from object? Seems an odd thing to do, though.

Comment: @Dani that answer was helpful too, thanks :)

Comment: @JohnRC besides console.log I tried to use that array but it also shows that it's undefined. The problem was the method that I used to get the data from mongo, thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log `user.toJSON()` and see is there any push_subscription key is present.
try `user.toJSON().push_subscriptions` as user is a mongoose Document you can try `toJSON` or `toObject`

As already discussed in [Mongoose creating empty arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713650/mongoose-creating-empty-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

you can use .lean() method to convert user to plain object :

```
const user = await UserModel.findById(user_id).exec().lean();
```