# Mongoose leaves creates an empty array

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Inserted Object

```
newSale {
  productCode: 'MRS-GT-EN',
  amount: 359.89,
  serial: 4143,
  orderNumber: 2241,
  bookingDates: [
    { date: '9-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '10-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '11-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '12-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '13-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '14-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '15-1-2023', time: 6 },
    { date: '16-1-2023', time: 6 }
  ],
  delivered: false
}
```

with this Schema:

```
const saleSchema = new Schema({
    productCode: { type: String, required: true },
    amount: { type: Number, required: true },
    serial: { type: Number, required: true },
    orderNumber: { type: Number, required: true},
    bookindDates: [{date: {type: String}, time:{type:Number}}],
    delivered: { type: Boolean, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true})
```

When I review the DB saves everything fine except for `bookingDates`, it leaves an empty array.

I tried this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713650/mongoose-creating-empty-arrays) unsuccessfully.

I doing something wrong but I don't know what, any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `type` and `default` properties for `bookindDates`,

```
bookindDates: {
  type: [{ date: String, time: Number }]
  default: undefined
}
```

Comment: Not working, now it does not even create the empty array.

Comment: I was wondering if the problem is that im sending the whole array, but that does not makes any sense

Comment: It will not create an empty array, that you actually wanted, It should work, what is your insert document? and what is the mongoose npm version?

Comment: Im sending the data to the Schema exactly how it is in the upper code of the post. Also it saves everything else but the array. If you need more details here is the code to call the DB:

newSale(saleData){
        return this.db.then( _ => this.model.create(saleData)).then(resp => {
            return resp
        })
    }

Comment: Mongoose is 6.6.0

Answer (score 0):

```
bookingDates: {type:[{date: {type: String}, time:{type:Number}}], default: undefined},
```

This is how ended up working, but also the main problem was the property name in the Schema was misspelled bookindDates instead bookingDates.