# Mongoose schema to require array that can be empty

Tags: arrays, validation, mongoose, required

I have this schema

```
var StuffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

mongoose.model('Stuff', StuffSchema);
```

Works fine.

Now I need to add another schema "Cargo" containing this

```
mystuff: { type:[String], ref: 'Stuff', required:true},
```

that is, I want mystuff to contain array of ids of Stuff, but this fails with validation error when running this code

```
mongoose.model('Cargo').create( some data...)
```

if I use an empty array for the mystuff field.
It seems to work if I change the Cargo schema to

```
mystuff: { type:[String], ref: 'Stuff'},
```

but I want the mystuff field to be required and allow empty arrays

What can I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 15):

Empty arrays are created by default (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658152/why-does-mongoose-add-blank-arrays)). The attribute `required: true` requires the array to have at least one element in it ([source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema/array.js#L108)). You can remove that attribute to get your desired behavior.

(Aside, mongoose assigns a default `_id` field with the type ObjectId to all schemas. Declaring it is unnecessary, and using a string is not typical, although certainly allowed.)

**Edit Nov 2017**: This is a candidate change in Mongoose 5. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5139.

Comment: I don't think the schema type *has* to be ObjectId, it needs to be whatever the type of the identifier property of the referenced schema. See the example in the docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: As you suggested, the default behaviour has changed since version 5 of Mongoose. Quoting https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#array-required :
> In mongoose 5 the `required` validator only verifies if the value is an array. That is, it will not fail for _empty_ arrays as it would in mongoose 4.